# I have a large zip file of 13 GB i need to extract it in gdrive on google colab. I have tried unzip but it didn't work. i tried 7zip it giving error

Tags: zip, google-colaboratory, unzip, 7zip

```
    7-Zip [64] 16.02 : Copyright (c) 1999-2016 Igor Pavlov : 2016-05-21
    p7zip Version 16.02 (locale=en_US.UTF-8,Utf16=on,HugeFiles=on,64 bits,2 CPUs Intel(R) 
    Xeon(R) CPU @ 2.20GHz (406F0),ASM,AES-NI)

    Scanning the drive for archives:
    1 file, 13510573713 bytes (13 GiB)

    Extracting archive: image_train.zip
    --
    Path = image_train.zip 
    Type = zip
    Physical Size = 13510573713
    64-bit = +


    ERROR: Unknown error -2147024894

    Archives with Errors: 1
```

> it seems like one of the file is corrupt that's why it's giving this error. how can i ignore a corrupt file ?or if there is any other way?

Comment: did you check my answer? was it helpful or need any more support?

Comment: actuaaly no . i had tried your answer it worked on small size file ..  on   larger archive after extracting some file  it gives this error                                     ` file #1207565:  bad zipfile offset (local header sig):  9570252890
file #1207566:  bad zipfile offset (local header sig):  9570254437
file #1207567:  bad zipfile offset (local header sig):  9570255044
file #1207568:  bad zipfile offset (local header sig):  9570256141
file #1207569:  bad zipfile offset (local header sig):  9570256786
file #1207570:  bad zipfile offset (local header sig):  9570257539`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can import zipfile and extract using the following commands. These commands worked for me.

```
import zipfile
!unzip My_big_file.zip -d My_extracted_file
```